# Memory management in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, memory-management

My query is how can i store data in secondary memory by fetching it from database and then displaying it in small units using zend framework coding ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to work out exactly what you mean. If you are finding database access too slow, then you should use caching to store the results received from the database into files or memory. If you are storing to memory, then the memcached server is very popular.

Zend Framework provides the Zend_Cache component to help you manage storing, retreiving and expiring cached data. It also allows you to easily change the "back end" storage system from file to memcached so that you can compare performance.

Some useful links:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html
- http://www.talkincode.com/a-simple-introduction-to-zend_cache-1048.html
- http://www.slideshare.net/akrabat/caching-for-performance

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Zend_Cache and Zend_Paginator with ArrayAdapter